# How to store value of specific cell from console output table in a variable on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, command-line

I have to get process id of process running against port 8080 hence executed command -

```
lsof -i :8080
```

It returns output like -

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    2576 root   28u  IPv4 6582151      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

I want to get value of PID in variable. I tried following, but it returns values from second column of output -

```
var=$(lsof -i :8080 | awk '{print $2}')
echo $var
```

Output is -

```
PID 2576
```

Please guide me on how to collect value of specific cell value from output.

Comment: Use `awk 'NR==2 {print $2}'` to only print column 2 of the second line.

Comment: Thanks @Devon, this helped!

Comment: Or use the `-t` option of `lsof` in addition and omit the `awk`.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar, thanks for the input but can you please share command to get process id running against specific port with -t option?

Comment: To make my previous comment clear to the extreme: `var=$(lsof -i :8080 -t)` . Not that this will of course catch ''all'' process ids that use the port.

Comment: THanks @R.J.Mathar, your solution also helped to achieve this.